# Pug + v-for + prettier неправильно форматируется, как пофиксить?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, pug

Использую VSCode.
Пример:

```
<template lang="pug">
  item(v-for="item, index in list")
</template>
```

prettier форматирует в:

```
<template lang="pug">
  item(v-for="(item, index in list)")
</template>
```

Зачем мне лишние "(" и ")" из-за них у меня возникает ошибка:

```
  Errors compiling template:
  invalid expression: Unexpected token ')' in
    directory)
  Raw expression: v-for="(item, index in list)"
```

Comment: a с помощью Vetur не пробовали форматировать?

Comment: Подозреваю, что Vetur использует prettier, так как он у него находиться в зависимостях. Vetur у меня используется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, во vue шаблоне всегда должен быть один корневой элемент.

Во-вторых, в синтаксисе v-for ошибка: если нужны item и index, их нужно взять в скобки. Только "item, index", без "in list"

```html
<template lang="pug">
  div
    item(v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index")
</template>
```

Comment: Корневой элемент не указал в примере, видимо торопился. Если поставить скобки вручную как в вашем ответе - помогает. Спасибо.